# Working with multiple views using HTML and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I have two tabs `user` and `admin` that render their own tables with separate sets of data. The tables have checkboxes on both tab views. How do I maintain the state of the data and the checkboxes in each view while I am constantly switching between them.

Also, I have noticed that I have a lot of duplicate HTML and JS code since the IDs of the HTML elements have to be unique in both tabs while they are very similar in appearance on both views (needs to be).

So far I have tried HTML5's `LocalStorage` to save the state of each tab contents but its not really getting me anywhere. Is JQuery's `.clone()` good enough to maintain what I want?

`***Note: I am expecting some suggestions based on industry practices since I think this would be a very common problem.***`

What would be an efficient solution for tabbed layout using HTML and JS?

Comment: Do you destroy the old tab context for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using a single page application you can simply save the state in a simple js object (model).
if its on different web pages local storage or session storage would give you the solution. what is not working for you with LocalStorage? its an adequate solution, especially if you want the state to be saved after you close and reopen the browser